# Java method names: useXxx() vs. setXxx()

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Is there a general guideline for prefixing Java method names with `useXxx()` vs. `setXxx()`?

I tried to call the `setDelimiter()` method of the Scanner class, only to find it was named `useDelimiter()`.  The JavaDoc describes this method as "*Sets* this scanner's delimiting pattern..."

So, why `useXxx()` instead of `setXxx()`?

Comment: your question is just like _what is the difference between "eat bread" and "digest bread"?_

Comment: Fire in the hole! We've found a Java creator that didn't followed the JavaBean coding standards! Let's burn down his house!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not the standard setter method. its set the delimPattern and return Scanner object

```
 public Scanner useDelimiter(Pattern pattern) {
    delimPattern = pattern;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Naming methods `.setXxx()` or `.getXxx()` is just a convention for [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javabeans). If you don't explicitly use your class as a bean (and `Scanner` certainly isn't one), you can name your methods however you like.

Also, this `.useDelimiter()` method returns `this`, whereas JavaBeans setters return `void`. If this method did follow the bean convention, you could not be able to write:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(xxx);
```

The only real convention to method names, except if you do intend your class to be a bean, should be that they are self explanative.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely inconsistent.

I would normally expect accessors to be of the form `setX`/`getX` (or `isX` for booleans). This is [part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) of the JavaBeans convention. A lot of frameworks and tools are coded explicitly to work this way and you'll lose interoperability if you ignore it.

Note that it's not *incorrect*, however. But I would try to maintain a level of interoperability regardless.

Comment: Well, `Scanner` is not a bean to start with.

Answer (score 0):

"setXXX()" and "getXXX()" are more than "conventions" - the names are also recognized as "getter" and "setter" methods by Java Beans.  If your class happens to be a Java Bean.  Class "Scanner" isn't :)

Otherwise, it's just a matter preference.

Answer (score 0):

In Java setXxx() method, 'set' is used to set a value, for example to set the ID of a manager:

```
 public void setManagerID()
 {
      String managerID = null;

    managerID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input an ID:");

  }
```